# Pass a vector of column names into dplyr::summarize to get max/min

Tags: r, dplyr, max, summarize

I would like to do this:

```
data %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarize(maxVal = max(Val),
              maxVal2 = max(Val2))
```

However, I have a lot of columns I would like to get the Max of. I would like to pass in a vector of columns like this:

```
cols <- c("Val", "Val2")
data %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarize(max(cols))
```

However, this does not work. How do I fix the syntax to do this easily?

Comment: Use `summarise_at(vars(cols), max)` or if you need add to suffix `summarise_at(vars(cols), funs(max = max(.)))`

Comment: How would I prefix it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we wanted to have a prefix name after `summarize`ing the multiple columns, then use `rename_at`

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(cols), max) %>%
   rename_at(-1, ~ paste0('max', .))
```

As a reproducible example, used the `data(mtcars)`

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(mpg, disp), max) %>% 
  rename_at(-1, ~ paste0('max', .))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
#   gear maxmpg maxdisp
#  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
#1     3   21.5    472 
#2     4   33.9    168.
#3     5   30.4    351
```